# Not able to pass multiple JSON objects to ajax query

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following JSON objects:

```
var algo, encrypt, nameOfRecord, configOutput = new Object();

algo = JSON.parse('{"algorithm" :"'+response.fieldConfigProperties.algorithmNames+'"}');
encrypt = JSON.parse('{"encryptionLevel" :"'+response.fieldConfigProperties.encryptionLevels+'"}');
nameOfRecord = JSON.parse('{"recordName" :"'+recordName+'"}');
configOutput = JSON.parse('{"outputConfiguration" :"'+outputConfiguration+'"}');
```

How do i pass all of them at once to my ajax jQuery?

This is my jquery

```
$.ajax({
        headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        url:"/FeildConfigurationServlet",
        method:"POST",
        data: //WHAT SHOULD I PASS HERE
        dataType:"json",

        success:function(response){
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                            console.log('success /FeildConfigurationServlet')

                        } })
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks:)

EDIT:

This is the rest service i have to call:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/FeildConfigurationServlet", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
// writes a new field config details or update an already existing field
// configuration
protected @ResponseBody String feildConfigurationServlet(@RequestBody FieldConfigurationData fcd) {

    String algorithm = fcd.getAlgorithm();
    String encryptionLevel = fcd.getEncryptionLevel();
    String fieldValueToBeConfigured = fcd.getFieldValueToBeConfigured();
    String recordName = fcd.getRecordName();
    String outputConfiguration = fcd.getOutputConfiguration();



    String fileNameBigDataXML = CommonUtils.getConfigFolderPath()
            + "\\Config-XML\\tap-dap-anonymizer-configuration.xml";
    String dataReadFieldOutputConfig = null;
    String dataReadRecordStructure = null;
    try {
        dataReadFieldOutputConfig = readDataFromFile(
                CommonUtils.getConfigFolderPath() + "\\Config-XML\\field_output_config.xml");
        dataReadRecordStructure = readDataFromFile(
                CommonUtils.getConfigFolderPath() + "\\Config-XML\\record_structure.xml");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // read data from bigdata XML and from fieldconfig XML
    String dataRead = null;
    try {
        dataRead = readDataFromFile(fileNameBigDataXML);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // to append record sturcture(to get output under that fieldname)
    dataRead = appendRecordStructureForRecordType(dataRead, dataReadRecordStructure, recordName,
            fieldValueToBeConfigured);
    // manipulations for the data
    String finalDataForFieldOutputConfig = generateGenericFieldConfigStructure(dataReadFieldOutputConfig,
            fieldValueToBeConfigured, outputConfiguration, algorithm, encryptionLevel);
    // manipulated data whether to add or to update
    try {
        addOrUpdateFieldConfig(dataRead, fieldValueToBeConfigured, finalDataForFieldOutputConfig,
                fileNameBigDataXML, recordName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // sending response
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("success", true);
    return jsonObject.toString();
}

public static String appendRecordStructureForRecordType(String dataRead, String dataReadRecordStructure,
        String recordName, String fieldValueToBeConfigured) {

    dataReadRecordStructure = dataReadRecordStructure.replaceFirst("<dap-property-value></dap-property-value>",
            "<dap-property-value>" + fieldValueToBeConfigured + "_hash</dap-property-value>");
    String firstpart = dataRead.substring(0, dataRead.indexOf("<record-name>" + recordName + "</record-name>"));
    String lastPart = dataRead.substring(dataRead.indexOf("<record-name>" + recordName + "</record-name>"));
    String changeToAppend = lastPart.substring(0, lastPart.indexOf("</record-structure>")) + dataReadRecordStructure
            + lastPart.substring(lastPart.indexOf("</record-structure>"));
    String finaldataRead = firstpart + changeToAppend;
    return finaldataRead;

}

public static String generateGenericFieldConfigStructure(String dataReadFieldOutputConfig,
        String fieldValueToBeConfigured, String outputConfiguration, String algorithm, String encryptionLevel) {

    dataReadFieldOutputConfig = dataReadFieldOutputConfig.replaceFirst("<field-reference></field-reference>",
            "<field-reference>" + fieldValueToBeConfigured + "</field-reference>");
    dataReadFieldOutputConfig = dataReadFieldOutputConfig.replaceFirst(
            "<drop-original-field></drop-original-field>",
            "<drop-original-field>" + outputConfiguration + "</drop-original-field>");
    dataReadFieldOutputConfig = dataReadFieldOutputConfig.replaceFirst("<algorithm></algorithm>",
            "<algorithm>" + algorithm + "</algorithm>");

    dataReadFieldOutputConfig = dataReadFieldOutputConfig.replaceFirst(
            "<field-operation-name></field-operation-name>",
            "<field-operation-name>" + fieldValueToBeConfigured + "_hash</field-operation-name>");
    String firstData = dataReadFieldOutputConfig
            .substring(dataReadFieldOutputConfig.lastIndexOf("<operation-configuration>"));
    String data = dataReadFieldOutputConfig.substring(0,
            dataReadFieldOutputConfig.lastIndexOf("<operation-configuration>") - 1);
    firstData = firstData.replace("<algorithm></algorithm>", "<algorithm>" + encryptionLevel + "</algorithm>");
    dataReadFieldOutputConfig = data + firstData;
    return dataReadFieldOutputConfig;
}

public static void addOrUpdateFieldConfig(String dataRead, String fieldValueToBeConfigured,
        String finalDataForFieldOutputConfig, String fileNameBigDataXML, String recordName) throws IOException {
    if (dataRead.contains("<field-reference>" + fieldValueToBeConfigured + "</field-reference>")) {
        // to be updated
        int fieldReferenceIndex = dataRead
                .indexOf("<field-reference>" + fieldValueToBeConfigured + "</field-reference>");
        String firstPartdataRead = dataRead.substring(0, fieldReferenceIndex);
        String remainingPartdataread = dataRead.substring(fieldReferenceIndex - 1);
        // to be appended to remaining part
        String inbet = StringUtils.substringBetween(finalDataForFieldOutputConfig, "<field-operations>",
                "</field-operations>");
        // first and last index of field <field-operations>
        remainingPartdataread = remainingPartdataread.substring(0,
                remainingPartdataread.indexOf("<field-operations>")) + "<field-operations>" + inbet
                + remainingPartdataread.substring(remainingPartdataread.indexOf("</field-operations>"));
        dataRead = firstPartdataRead + remainingPartdataread;
        writeToFile(dataRead, fileNameBigDataXML);
        logger.debug("This is updating field config details : " + "writing field data to file : " + dataRead);
    } else {
        // for a new field config
        int recordReferenceIndex = dataRead.indexOf("<record-reference>" + recordName + "</record-reference>");
        String firstPartdataRead = dataRead.substring(0, recordReferenceIndex);
        String remainingPartdataread = dataRead.substring(recordReferenceIndex - 1);
        String LastPartBigData = remainingPartdataread.substring(0,
                remainingPartdataread.indexOf("</record-anonymizer-configuration>")) + finalDataForFieldOutputConfig
                + remainingPartdataread
                        .substring(remainingPartdataread.indexOf("</record-anonymizer-configuration>") - 1);
        dataRead = firstPartdataRead + LastPartBigData;
        writeToFile(dataRead, fileNameBigDataXML);
        logger.debug("This is writing new field config details : " + "writing field data to file : " + dataRead);
    }
}
```

I have to pass all the objects to this service. How do i do that?

UPDATE:
I forgot to add this class

```
package com.entity;

public class FieldConfigurationData {

private String algorithm;
private String encryptionLevel;
private String fieldValueToBeConfigured;
private String recordName;
private String outputConfiguration;

public String getAlgorithm() {
    return algorithm;
}

public void setAlgorithm(String algorithm) {
    this.algorithm = algorithm;
}

public String getEncryptionLevel() {
    return encryptionLevel;
}

public void setEncryptionLevel(String encryptionLevel) {
    this.encryptionLevel = encryptionLevel;
}

public String getFieldValueToBeConfigured() {
    return fieldValueToBeConfigured;
}

public void setFieldValueToBeConfigured(String fieldValueToBeConfigured) {
    this.fieldValueToBeConfigured = fieldValueToBeConfigured;
}

public String getRecordName() {
    return recordName;
}

public void setRecordName(String recordName) {
    this.recordName = recordName;
}

public String getOutputConfiguration() {
    return outputConfiguration;
}

public void setOutputConfiguration(String outputConfiguration) {
    this.outputConfiguration = outputConfiguration;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "FeildConfigurationData [algorithm=" + algorithm + ", encryptionLevel=" + encryptionLevel
            + ", fieldValueToBeConfigured=" + fieldValueToBeConfigured + ", recordName=" + recordName
            + ", outputConfiguration=" + outputConfiguration + "]";
}

}
```

Comment: i'm not sure if you want to send JSON in the request or you just think JSON is sent in the request. How are you going to parse the data on the servlet?

Comment: i want to send it as JSON only..the servlet is saving the data as JSON in some other file.

Comment: You definition of `FieldConfigurationData` is missing also you aren't sending `fieldValueToBeConfigured` in the request.

Comment: i forgot to add the class that i am using..did that

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new object which contains the JSON objects data

```
  $.ajax({
            headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            url:"/FeildConfigurationServlet",
            method:"POST",
            data: {
             algo:algo,
             encrypt:encrypt,
             nameOfRecord:nameOfRecord,
             configOutput:configOutput 
            },
            dataType:"json",

            success:function(response){
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                                console.log('success /FeildConfigurationServlet')

                            } })
```

Comment: The data is a single object. However, you can pass multiple objects inside of an object, so. Voila!

Comment: @Vladu Ionut actually i want to send a value which is like this

Comment: {
 "algorithm":"HmacSHA256",
 "encryptionLevel":"RSA",
 "fieldValueToBeConfigured":"Mobile",
 "recordName":"CRM1",
 "outputConfiguration":"YES"
}
this works fine in postman. I do not want it to be hardcoded as it may change

Comment: when i try your way i get "Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'algo': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') error

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple attributes to data, as you can read [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). So you can simply use `data: {"algo": algo, "encrypt": encrypt ...}`

Comment: i get this "Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'algo': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') error

Comment: Could you please post the exact code you had, when you got this error? Just update your question. Thanks in advance

Comment: And do you get this error in your console? Can you tell us in which line the error occurs? YOu can see this i.e. in Chrome's developer console

Answer (score 0):

```
     var algo, encrypt, nameOfRecord, configOutput = new Object();
    var Obj = new Object();
    algo = JSON.parse('{"algorithm" :"'+response.fieldConfigProperties.algorithmNames+'"}');
    encrypt = JSON.parse('{"encryptionLevel" :"'+response.fieldConfigProperties.encryptionLevels+'"}');
    nameOfRecord = JSON.parse('{"recordName" :"'+recordName+'"}');
    configOutput = JSON.parse('{"outputConfiguration" :"'+outputConfiguration+'"}');

   Obj = {algo, encrypt, nameOfRecord, configOutput}
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't build JSON by hand, especially if you're going to parse it into an object anyway.

```
var data = {
    algorithm :response.fieldConfigProperties.algorithmNames,
    encryptionLevel: response.fieldConfigProperties.encryptionLevels,
    recordName: recordName,
    outputConfiguration: outputConfiguration,
    fieldValueToBeConfigured: 'some value'
};
```

When sending json you should set the content type to application/json, and pass you js data as json

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/FeildConfigurationServlet",
    method:"POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType:"json",

    success:function(response){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        console.log('success /FeildConfigurationServlet')

    } 
});
```

Comment: i tried this method..but i am getting
"Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token

Comment: Well without your server side code we cant really help any more

Comment: i have added the rest service code that i have to call. Please have a look.

Comment: Try sending the `fieldValueToBeConfigured` field in your ajax request.